# How to average a matrix of lists?

Tags: r, list, matrix, statistics

I have a complicated computation question about averaging a matrix of lists...

The matrix looks like

```
mat <- matrix(list(), 100, 10)
```

Each cell is filled with a list of 3 elements. For example, the mat[,1] will look like

```
mat[,1]
```

[[1]]

[1] 1.21 1.33 1.50

[[2]]

[1] 2.1 1.9 4.5

[[3]]

[1] 0.1 0.4 1.5

...

[[100]]

[1] 0.8 0.69 1.42

I hope to take average of all the first elements in the 100 lists. In other words, it's to compute (1.21 + 2.1 + 0.1 + ... + 0.8)/100. Similarly, it can apply to all the second elements, as (1.33 + 1.9 + 0.4 + ... + 0.69)/100. And the third elements too... If possible, it can apply this procedure to all the 10 columns in mat.

How can this be achieved using lapply or sapply function?

Comment: It is best to give an small example. For example a matrix of smaller size.

Comment: Similar to Thomas' attempt I think `apply(mat, 2, function(x) colMeans(do.call(rbind, x)))` should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `dplyr` function bind_cols to bind each of list in `mat[, i]`,
and the take the row means.

```
res_in_cols <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) rowMeans(dplyr::bind_cols(x)))
```

The averages for `mat[, i]` is in the ith column of `res_in_cols`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `colMeans` + `rbind` along with `apply`

```
as.matrix(asplit(apply(mat, 2, function(x) colMeans(do.call(rbind, x))), 2))
```

Comment: OP is  after column_sum / nrow(mat). Also, I tried this and it doesn't give column means after unlisting them - maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: @Suren I guess OP wants to obtain a length-3 array for each cell

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. I guess I haven't read the question well.